# Android layout button next to 3 textviews

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I currently have a layout which holds 3 textviews.

My question is how to create a button next to those textviews.

Currently my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/release_at"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This creates me 3 Textviews, my idea is to put a button right to the textviews, but I do not know how to do that properly.

Comment: try my solution and let me have your feedback. As I meintionned, you just need to play on arounf the margin and padding position/align the buttons and text views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    heigth=match_parent
    width=match_parent
    orientation=horizontal
    <LinearLayout
        heigth=match_parent
        width=0dp
        layout_weigth=1
        orientation=vertical
        //Your textviews
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        heigth=match_parent
        width=0dp
        layout_weigth=1
        orientation=vertical
        gravity="right"
        //Your button
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Putting gravity right aligns the button to the right.

Comment: Hi this works so far I think, but How can I center so to say that button to all 3 textviews and align that button to the right?

Comment: Thanks looks great, I will accept it in a few minutes

Comment: Ah not all buttons are same aligned the same

Comment: thought you only need 1 button?

Comment: I got a list with multiple listviews each one has 3 textviews, if the text is shorter the button moves more to the left how to solve that?

Comment: Ok I made it work, I made an edit to your answer if that is ok

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is this, but the better one is using [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/release_at"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use horizontal LinearLayouts Inside your main vertical LinearLayout as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:text="Name ......"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nameButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Name" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/descriptionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/release_at"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Release at"
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/releaseButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Release" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean after every textview one button ? If you need one button after every textview use this .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/release_at"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No I meant for 3 textviews 1 button :) but thanks anyways